# Sorting grouped bar plots dependently in Plotly

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, plotly, bar-chart

I've 3 x-values (Grouped Bar Chart) for each row which are separated by name (the plot below), displayed using `fig.update_xaxes(categoryorder='category ascending')`.
The values are dependent on the name column.
[image]
A, B, C.
It'll always sort based on the **A** value, I want to sort it based on **B** and **C** independently. (sorting by largest red, which the fifth red value should come first, then sorting by largest brown).
how can I achieve that without repeating myself?
**Complete Reproducible Code:**
want to sort players first by `Weight` then by `Height` and at the end, by `Score`.
like this:
first sort by `Weight`: [Dante, Evan, Arthur, Carlos, Frank, Bneson]
second sort by `Height`: [Arthur, Frank, Dante, Carlos, Evan, Benson]...
[image: full sample]

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

dftst = pd.DataFrame([('Arthur', 110, 200, 10),
                   ('Benson', 50, 160, 12),
                   ('Carlos', 90, 170, 14),
                   ('Dante', 160, 180, 11),
                   ('Evan', 130, 165, 18),
                   ('Frank', 70, 190, 20)],
           columns=('Name', 'Weight', 'Height', 'Score'))

pnames = dftst['Name']
x = list(range(len(pnames)))

bar_plots = [
  go.Bar(x=x, y=dftst['Weight'], name='Weight', marker=go.bar.Marker(color='#0343df')),
  go.Bar(x=x, y=dftst['Height'], name='Height', marker=go.bar.Marker(color='#e50000')),
  go.Bar(x=x, y=dftst['Score'], name='Score', marker=go.bar.Marker(color='green')),
]

layout = go.Layout(
  title=go.layout.Title(text="Players", x=0.5),
  yaxis_title="Players Details",
  xaxis_tickmode="array",
  xaxis_tickvals=list(range(6)),
  xaxis_ticktext=tuple(dftst['Name'].values))

fig = go.Figure(data=bar_plots, layout=layout)

fig.update_layout(
    autosize=False,
    width=600,
    height=700)

fig.update_layout(barmode='group', xaxis={'categoryorder':'category ascending'})

fig.update_xaxes(
    showgrid=True,
    ticks="outside",
    tickson="boundaries",
    ticklen=20
)

fig.show()
```

Comment: [it's not possible?!](https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/#:~:text=for%20more%20information.-,Note%20that%20sorting%20the%20bars%20by%20a%20particular%20trace%20isn%27t%20possible%20right%20now%20%2D%20it%27s%20only%20possible%20to%20sort%20by%20the%20total%20values.,-Of%20course%2C%20you)

Answer (score 0):

- if columns are independent, you can treat them as independent series
- hence create by a list of sorted series
- fix up trace names (and legend) by updating traces

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({c: np.random.randint(1, 100, 40) for c in "ABC"})

fig = px.bar(y=[df[c].sort_values(ascending=0) for c in df.columns],barmode="group")

for t, c in zip(fig.data, df.columns):
    t.update(name=c)

fig
```

Comment: thanks, they're dependent on the name of that column, doing this changes their values and results in false info.

Comment: I'd suggest updating the question to fully define in plain English what is dependent and what is independent.  effectively a data dictionary, for me if you know relational tuple algebra define in those terms

Comment: I've updated my question and I think it looks stupid! but I really don't know what is the best way to sort traces efficiently more than one time, without writing the same code 3 times!